# Connections between Quip and Zapier are throwing a 400 error

Tags: quip, liveapps

Zapier is encountering a connection error with Quip.

URL:

```
https://platform.quip.com/1/oauth/login?client_id=INTEGRATION-9&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fzapier.com%2Fdashboard%2Fauth%2Foauth%2Freturn%2FQuipDevAPI%2F&response_type=code&state=1711552690.792863463373
```

Error:

```
{
"error": "application_error",
"error_code": 400,
"error_description": "Invalid client_id"
}
```

Comment: Why does the error description not say it all? Is the request from Zapier or from Quip? What is the context anyway? Please add much more detail to your question.

Comment: I've updated the description with the URL. This request is from Zapier to Quip